# We need to track the user where ever he goes, whether he is indoor or outdoor

Tags: android, location, android-gps, indoor-positioning-system

We need to track the user where ever he goes, whether he is in house or outdoor.

We have used FusedLocationApi with GoogleApiClient to get location updates of user.

FusedLocationApi will take Gps and wifi network and give accurate location among them.

This worked fine if the user is outdoor(under open sky so that Gps can coomunicate with salillite and give location updates) but if the user  indoor,FusedLocationApi did not give the accurate result of users location.In this case its showing the users location very far from users current location

We need accurate location of the user even though the user is indoor.

We have started research on it.

We found that Android P will give 1 meter accuracy of location with WIFI-RTT

The Wi-Fi Round Trip Time (RTT) feature in Android 9 enables supporting devices to measure a distance to other supporting devices: 
whether they are Access Points (APs) or Wi-Fi Aware peers (if Wi-Fi Aware is supported on the device). This feature, built upon the IEEE 802.11mc protocol, 
enables apps to use enhanced location accuracy and awareness.

I am new to Android, I am not able to understand what i have to do by achieving indoor location accuracy.please someone help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Indoor positioning is a complex topic depending on what exactly you would like to achieve. Even with the new API provided by Android 9 it is not as easy as using the FusedLocationApi for example: you still need to gather information about which AP is where. Based on that knowledge you have to implement algorithms that determine where you are based on the APs you receive signals from.

There is lots of companies offering indoor positioning as a product nowadays. I might be biased, but I'd recommend checking out [indoo.rs](https://indoo.rs/).

Comment: can we get latlongs of the users current location with paid versions as you said indoo.rs?

Comment: I have found  http://www.indooratlas.com/  this for indoor navigation without beacons but i am unable to do it.can anyone please check this and explain me how can i complete my task by using this.If anyone already used it,please reply need urgent help.

Comment: Yes, you can get latlong of a user's current location using solutions like indoo.rs. I can't comment on indooratlas as I don't have experience using them.